# Alamofire 4 swift 3 - https with credentials

Tags: swift, https, alamofire, credentials

i want to go via https with user and password on a Server and get some JSON Feeds using Alamofire 4 on Swift 3

```
 let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://myserver.com:123/apps/?cmd=getjson")!)
    let urlString = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString

    let user = "myuser"
    let passwort = "one password"

    let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: passwort, persistence: .forSession)

     let configuration =  URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15
    let almomanager = SessionManager(configuration:configuration)

    almomanager.request( urlString! )
        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

but it fails with

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
```

with an older Version of Alamofire and Swift it works fine! 
Where i my mistake??

Comment: are you using Alamofire version 4?

Comment: yes, i am using Alamofire 4

Comment: may be you need to update pod

Comment: pod is also updated!

Comment: I also updated the info.plist with  AppTransportSecurity -> AllowsArbitraryLoad -> Yes

Comment: Are you using digest protocol?